# Union and intersect equivlance

Tags: probability, statistics

Let's take two events independent events $A$ and $B$

Is $P[(A\cap B) \cup (B \cap B)]=P[A \cap B] \cup P[B \cap B]$ ?

I know that for $P[A \cap B]=P[A]P[B]$ if they are independent, but i don't know what i can say about just $[A \cap B]$

Comment: This is a bit of a mess: You're unioning two probabilities on the right hand side, which is nonsense. Also, because of how you've written it, $(A \cap B) \cup (B \cap B) = B$, so the left side is *really* easy to deal with.

Comment: LHS is $B$ as noted in the comment above.  Besides, OP, not sure what your question is, in the first place.

Comment: Do not confuse _disjointness_ (logical property) with _independence_ (probability property). If $A$ and $B$ are disjoint, then $P(A \cup B)  = P(A)+P(B).$ If $A$ and $B$ are indep., then $P(A\cap B) = P(A)P(B)$ so also $P(A\cup B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A\cap B) = P(A) + P(B) - P(A)P(B).$ // In the first equation of your Question, note that $B \cap B = B.$ What is $(A \cap B) \cup  B?$ [See @user296602's Comment.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The probability for an intersection of *pairwise independent* events is the product of the probabilities for the events.   So if indeed $A,B$ are independent events, then: $$\mathsf P(A\cap B)=\mathsf P(A)\,\mathsf P(B)$$

The probability for a union of *pairwise disjoint* events (aka *mutually exclusive* events) is the sum of the probabilities for the events.   However, the events $A\cap B$ and $B\cap B$ are *not* disjoint (except in the special case when $A\cap B=\emptyset$).

The probability for a union of *any* two events is the sum of the probabilties for the events *minus* the probability for their intersection.   (This is the base case for the *principle of inclusion and exclusion*.)

$$\mathsf P((A\cap B)\cup(B\cap B)) ~=~ \mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(B\cap B)-\mathsf P((A\cap B)\cap(B \cap B))$$

---

Also, $B\cap B= B$, and $(A\cap B)\cap (B\cap B)=(A\cap B)$, so this simplifies down to the self evident: $${\mathsf P(B)~=~\mathsf P(A\cap B)+\mathsf P(B)-\mathsf P(A\cap B)\\ \therefore ~~~0~=~0}$$

Comment: Thank you.  I wasn't sure about $P(A \cap B \cap B)$ being $P(A \cap B)$ but it makes sense.  I wanted to clarify that.